# Can I change the color of the part of the text that is in the different background?

Tags: html, css

I would like to do this https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kqldb.jpg
I want to change text from white to black color if it doesn't have the yellow background/img background.
I tried to use mix-blend-mode and filter:invert() but it wasn't working for me.

Thanks for your help!

There is my current html/css.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 5rem;
}

p {
  font-size: 2.25rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Headline</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. 
        Mollitia saepe reprehenderit nihil quam facere odio 
        eveniet modi in earum impedit non id, est vero. Non 
        culpa reprehenderit magni?
    </p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. 
        Alias, unde. Porro sunt neque ullam atque? Ipsam nesciunt 
        animi architecto! Consequatur maxime dolorum eius placeat 
        animi.
    </p>
    <img src="https://svgshare.com/i/R7P.svg" alt="">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`mix-blend-mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode) might help here.

```css
h1,
p {
  mix-blend-mode: color;
}

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 5rem;
}

p {
  font-size: 2.25rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Headline</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Mollitia saepe reprehenderit nihil quam facere odio eveniet modi in earum impedit non id, est vero. Non culpa reprehenderit magni?
  </p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias, unde. Porro sunt neque ullam atque? Ipsam nesciunt animi architecto! Consequatur maxime dolorum eius placeat animi.
  </p>
  <img src="https://svgshare.com/i/R7P.svg" alt="">
</body>

</html>
```

---

blending the image over the text and increasing contrast might also help but will modify the colors too.:

```css
img {
filter:contrast(200%);
mix-blend-mode: luminosity;
}

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 5rem;
}

p {
  font-size: 2.25rem;
}
```

```html
<h1>Headline</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Mollitia saepe reprehenderit nihil quam facere odio eveniet modi in earum impedit non id, est vero. Non culpa reprehenderit magni?
  </p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias, unde. Porro sunt neque ullam atque? Ipsam nesciunt animi architecto! Consequatur maxime dolorum eius placeat animi.
  </p>
  <img src="https://svgshare.com/i/R7P.svg" alt="">
```

background-clip can also be another approach using twice your svg shape (a white one as a background and a yellow one to show.

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB3aWR0aD0iNzM3IiBoZWlnaHQ9IjY5NCIgdmlld0JveD0iMCAwIDczNyA2OTQiIGZpbGw9Im5vbmUiIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyI+DQo8cGF0aCBkPSJNNTU3LjUgMjI0LjVDNTg0IDQzMSAyMzYuNjAzIDcwOC43OCAtNzEgNjkzTC04Ny41IC0xOTguNUw3MzYuNSAtMjM5QzU4OS42MTcgLTE0LjQ3MjQgNTMxIDE4IDU1Ny41IDIyNC41WiIgZmlsbD0iI0ZGRiIvPg0KPC9zdmc+) 0 0 no-repeat black;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
  color: transparent;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 5rem;
}

p {
  font-size: 2.25rem;
}

div svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Headline</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Mollitia saepe reprehenderit nihil quam facere odio eveniet modi in earum impedit non id, est vero. Non culpa reprehenderit magni?
  </p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias, unde. Porro sunt neque ullam atque? Ipsam nesciunt animi architecto! Consequatur maxime dolorum eius placeat animi.
  </p>
  <svg width="737" height="694" viewBox="0 0 737 694" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M557.5 224.5C584 431 236.603 708.78 -71 693L-87.5 -198.5L736.5 -239C589.617 -14.4724 531 18 557.5 224.5Z" fill="#F5DC00"/>
</svg>

</div>
```

Comment: ok, and can I change color of the changed text to white color?

Comment: plain white ? , probably not from yellow and black .

Comment: @Filip added another snippet to show another approach, but no plain white at that point. background-clip:text is also another approach to mind about

Answer (score 1):

You can use the span tag to divide and style your tag as you wish.

I have added them right on the letter of where your background color changes (on my screen to your code below so you may have to adjust it on yours.

(keep in mind that if your screen size changes/different device you'll have to adjust it using media queries)

HTML:

```
    <h1>Headline</h1>
  <p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetu</span>r adipisicing elit. 
        Mollitia saepe reprehenderit nihil quam facere odio 
        <span>eveniet modi in earum impedit non id,</span> est vero. Non 
        culpa reprehenderit magni?
    </p>
    <p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetu</span>r adipisicing elit. 
        Alias, unde. Porro sunt neque ullam atque? Ipsam <span>nesciunt 
        animi architecto! Consequatur</span> maxime dolorum eius placeat 
        animi.
```

CSS:

```
    h1 {
  font-size: 5rem;
  color: white;
}

p {
  font-size: 2.25rem;
}

p span {
  color: white;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I would like to make this automatically and for example have half of one letter with white color and the second half of the letter with black color like this https://imgur.com/a/fdR26IS

Comment: For the half/half check out this: https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/css/how-to-apply-css-styles-to-only-the-half-of-a-word-or-character.html

Comment: No problem, also, the reason why you can't do it automatically is because for the yellow part you are using an image. And there is no way for the CSS to read what way to color the text overtop of an image. If the yellow area was not an image and created through CSS then you could use CSS mix-blend-mode as seen here: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode

Comment: Oh ok, I thought CSS can read the color of the image... nevermind, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an HTML tag to control that part in Css. And give it a class or id to make up.

```
<p>Some text here for you and <span class="dif-bg">I want to help</span> you.</p>
```

You css should be like this :

```
.dif-bf{ background-color:black;}
```

It can help you to solve that.